# How to specify not equal selector in kubernetes service definition yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I am trying to create a service for a set of pods based on certain selectors. For example, the below `get pods` command retrieves the right pods for my requirement -

```
kubectl get pods --selector property1=dev,property2!=admin
```

Below is the extract of the service definition yaml where I am attempting to using the same selectors as above -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: port1
      port: 30303
      targetPort: 30303
  selector:
    property1: dev
    << property2: ???? >>>
```

I have tried `matchExpressions` without realizing that [service is not among the resources that support set-based filters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements). It resulted in the following error -

```
error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Service.spec.selector.matchExpressions): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServiceSpec.selector: got "array", expected "string"; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I am running upstream Kubernetes 1.12.5

Comment: Could you provide your `pod` YAML ? Also what kubernetes version are you using 1.16 or older?

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, Can you please elaborate what exactly are you looking for in the `pod.yaml`. Two reasons, 1. The above question is an abridged version of my environment. 2. The pods are not created by an yaml definition. But some other mechanism. So, the best I can do is run a `describe pod` and provide you the details you are interested in. k8s version 1.12.5. I will update version information in the question also.

Answer (score 3):

I've did some test but I am afraid it is not possible. As per [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors) API supports two types of selectors:

- [Equality-based](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#equality-based-requirement)
- [Set-based](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#set-based-requirement)

`kubeclt` allows to use operators like `=`,`==` and `!=`. So it works when you are using `$ kubectl get pods --selector property1=dev,property2!=admin`.

Configuration which you want to apply would work in `set-based` option as it supports `in`, `notin` and `exists`:

> environment in (production, qa)
>
> tier notin (frontend, backend)
>
> partition
>
> !partition

Unfortunately `set-based` is supported only by newer resurces as `Job`, `Deployment`, `Replica Set` and `Deamon Set` but is **not supporting `services`**.

More information about this can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#resources-that-support-set-based-requirements).

Even if you will set selector in YAML as:

```
property2: !value
```

In service, `property2` will be without any value.

`Selector:                 property1=dev,property2=`

As additional information `,` is recognized as `AND` in `services`.

As I am not aware how you are managing your cluster, the only thing I can advise is to redefine labels to use only `AND` as logical operator.

Comment: Funny it may sound, before seeing your response, I too tried `property2: !value` :) and got the same results :( And without any other option available, I have modified some labels and using a different set of selectors now. Thanks for your time!